# Blender is freezing when rendering: split kernel error: failed to load kernel_path_int

Tags: rendering

I'm running into an issue where I can't go any further with a tutorial. It keeps freezing when trying to render.  More information about my issue can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/lh0tvh/blender_is_freezing_when_rendering_split_kernel/